# Angular code smell "Either remove this import or add it as a dependency." when using an interface I wrote. How can I make my code compliant?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, angular8

I'm new to UI development so forgive me if this isn't angular. I'm using Angular 8 and typescript here. Anyways I created a pop-up modal that I wan't to use throughout my website. It looks great but when I plug it into my components like this

`import { IPopUpOptions, IPopUpButton } from 'src/app/modals/pop-up-modal/pop-up-options-interface';`

My SonarQube CI/CD pipeline says "Either remove this import or add it as a dependency. Dependencies should be explicitly listed in the package.json file. Importing a module that is not declared as a dependency makes it an implicit one and is bound to create problems." What does this mean? How can I use my pop-up properly so that it abides by this rule?

Comment: Maybe try adding './' to your import path: './src/app/modals/pop-...'? Without that, it might be seen as a dependency import (i.e., from node_modules) rather than a file system import.

Comment: My hero @MikeJ! Write that as the answer so I can give you credit =]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding `'./'` to your import path: `'./src/app/modals/pop-...'`. Without that, it might be seen as a dependency import (i.e., from node_modules) rather than a file system import.

Comment: what if we use @ as import? eg nx library?

Comment: @mikeJ Can you help with  question ? from Weijing Jay Lin comment

Comment: @WeijingJayLin did you find solution for the same ? I', also facing similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the rule with a whitelist property.
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/javascript-typescript-false-positive-with-absolute-imports/33290