# Typescript path resulting in module error

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I created a model named project to the existing project but when i import the class to another typescript file it throws the below error (VS2019)

import { Project } from "src/models/project";

ts2307 cannot find module "src/models/project" or its corresponding type declarations

please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670274/angular-code-smell-either-remove-this-import-or-add-it-as-a-dependency-when-u/59688362#59688362

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path instead of absolute path, so something like `../../models/project`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't configure `src` alias in the tsconfig.json, so change your tsconfig.json like below:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "src/*": [
                "./src/*"
        ],
    }
}
```